# Calling array from $.get function when get functions are done

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get

I need help calling the cagedMovies array when it is filled which is when both asynchronous functions are completed.

I've been trying to console.log cagedMovies which is an array of object once both $.get functions are finished so I can use the array for more functions.

I tried using jQuery.when with jQuery.done when both functions are completed and though I receive the alert the array that was console logged from Chrome says that the "Value below was Evaluated just now".

What should I do to set up the cagedMovies array for another function?

```
var cagedMovies = [];

$.when(pageLoop(), getMovies()).done(function(){
    alert("Done");
    console.log(cagedMovies); 
});

function pageLoop(){ 
    $.get(movieUrl, function(pageresponse) {
        for(var p = 1; p <= pageresponse['total_pages'] + 1; p++){
            getMovies(p);
        }
    }); 
}

function getMovies(page) {
    var p = page;
    var movieUrl = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=" + apiKey + "&language=en-US&" + sort + "&include_adult=false&include_video=true&page=1&with_people=" + nicolasCage + "&page=" + page;
    $.get(movieUrl, function(response) {
      for (var m = 0; m < response.results.length; m++){
        //Create a Genre array for each movie.
        var genre_array = [];
        //Set Genre response to a variable
        var genre_response = response['results'][m]['genre_ids'];
          for (var i = 0; i < genre_response.length; i++) {
            // Find the Genre by Genre ID
            var genre_obj = getGenreById(genre_response[i]);
            genre_array.push(genre_obj[0].name);
          };
        // function - makeObject
        var movieObject = createMovieObject(response['results'][m], genre_array);
          cagedMovies.push(movieObject);
        };
    }); 
};
```

Comment: return the result to calling `get`.

Comment: `pageLoop()` needs to do `return $.get(...)`

Comment: And so does `getMovies()`.

Comment: Thank you Barmar for your help! It's working but now I'm only getting the first twenty objects in cagedMovies and I still have other values that have loaded. What should I do to get all the values?